# only applying the angular router to part of the site?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Building an app with the angular router and Kirby CMS and hitting a slight problem.

I only wish to apply the angular router for certain sections of the site and others I want the router to "back off"..

```
/**
 * Handles all the routes for the app
 */
theApp.config(['$routeProvider','$locationProvider',
    function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
        $routeProvider.
            when('/', {
                templateUrl: '/assets/partials/pages/home.html'
            });
        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    }
]);
```

So the home page here picks up the path '/'... on the page there are some links to other areas of the site that I want to break out of the ang app...

eg:
'/about-us'

However, once the ang app has loaded it takes over all links on the page.. thus '/about-us' doesn't actually load..

How can I get around this? I want the router to recognise the request is not a ang match and redirect the browser completely.

Answer (score 0):

I have done this with mvc .net but maybe it also solves your problem. Angular takes care of the routing since the moment you enter the index file where you have declared your ng-app and the ng-view.

You can create a view where you declare your ng app and go from there to other views that will be rebdered inside ng-view using /#/view.html that routing will be controlled by angular and thus, those views should be declared in the routeprovider. However for those views out of angular you can redirect to them like usual and you will automatically leave angular behind.

Its recommended implementing the menu outside your ng-view and from the links of that menu use the angular url for the angular views or the other approach for the rest.

I hope you can apply this to your case

Comment: Yea I had considered this too.. this issue is mute with ang2 as server side rendering is possible. I wonder if there is a way of extending the router to allow the "otherwise" section to redirect the entire browser instead of an internal route to the app itself.

Comment: I get it but I haven't done it before. Maybe redirecting to a view where you just have a javascript that on Window.load redirects to another url? Not very clean though